# Website loads but pages are Blank, NO html code

Tags: php, html

When I go to the website, non-wordpress, the pages are blank. no content or images.

If I right click, the source code is also blank.

If go to a page on the site where a wordpress was uploaded, that page loads fine. It show content, images etc.

I can only access the site via FTP. I can not login using the CMS.

I did modify the httaccess file with assistance from another member here and it seemed to be working. Now every page is blank!

Q. Is this a permissions issue? or an Httacess issue?

The folder is set at 755 and files at 644.

Please help!!

.httacess file:

Header unset ETag
FileETag None

Header set Connection keep-alive

### EXPIRES HEADERS

ExpiresActive on

```
ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"
```

# CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

# Data interchange
    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed!)
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 year"

# HTML components (HTCs)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 month"

# HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

# JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/js "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 year"

# Manifest files
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

# Media
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

# Web feeds
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

# Web fonts
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"

```
</IfModule>

# Mod Rewrite
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# non-www (non-canonical) to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|staging\.|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Query String
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ FRAMEWORK.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&resource=$1& [L]

# redirect

Redirect 301 /oldpage.html www.newpage.com/TotalRoofWarranty.html
Redirect 301 /oldpage www.websitename.com/oldpage.html
Redirect 301 /oldpage.html www.websitename/newpage.html

# index redirect

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Gzip - compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have errors turned on?

Comment: `where a wordpress was uploaded` does not make a lot of sense. You should post your htaccess and try do describe the problem a bit more detailed. And check the error log for messages.

Comment: And posting the same question twice does not help either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468179/website-has-blank-pages-not-html-code

Comment: jeroen - sorry but it looked like you closed it.

Comment: jrod- not sure. I am noob. I have the log file and I posted the httacess file. In crisis mode so any help is appreciated.

Comment: NO Progress - still blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually means that you have fatal PHP errors on the page.

Check the logs for your web server for error messages if you have access.

If not, or if you don't get useful information, try putting this at the top of your page in a php tag:

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors","1");
```

This will show the error messages on the page. Warning: this will be visible to all visitors to your page, so only do this briefly and then remove it or comment it out.

Comment: Since you seem to be using shared hosting, look for errors.log, a file that typically logs any error messages.

Comment: I have the error log:  PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function session_is_registered() in httpdocs/_inc/inc.corefunctions.php on line 7

Comment: (13)Permission denied: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, referer:

Comment: schien - </IfModule> without matching <IfModule> section

Comment: It looks like you have some places to start fixing things now...

Comment: mellowfish87 - Created new httacess but getting:requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: mellowfish87 - still nothing. help!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any specific advice for `.htaccess` troubles, I can barely keep mine going. Maybe try opening a new question since this one was put on hold. Be very specific about the errors, include the full htaccess file in a code block, etc. People will help you if you play by the rules here.